# How to add custom grid as attribute to product in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, attributes, product-attribute, grid

I want to add tabs on the product page, to let admin to add unlimited tabs.

So fields in my grid will be: `id`, `position`, `tab label`, `tab content`.

Does anyone know how to do this? Maybe any tutorial exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the model created for the tab entity already (if not, find a tutorial or use mage2gen.com), this is how to make the tabs appear on the product page.

We make a plugin for `Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\View` that looks like this:

```
<?php


namespace Your\Module\Plugin\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product;

use Your\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Tab\Collection;
use Your\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Tab\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page;

class View
{
    /** @var  Your\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Tab\Collection */
    protected $tabCollection;

    public function __construct(CollectionFactory $collectionFactory)
    {
        $this->tabCollection = $collectionFactory->create();
    }

    public function beforePrepareAndRender(
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\View $subject, Page $resultPage, ...$args
    ) : array
    {
        $layout = $resultPage->getLayout();

        $detailsBlock = $layout->getBlock('product.info.details');

        // add tabs to the details block
        /** @var Your\Module\Api\Data\TabInterface $tab */
        foreach ($this->tabCollection->addOrder('position', Collection::SORT_ORDER_ASC) as $tab)
        {
            $name = "tab_" . $tab->getTabId();
            $tabBlock = $layout->createBlock(
                "Your\Module\Block\Tab",
                $name,
                ['tab' => $tab, 'data' => ['title' => __($tab->getLabel())]]
            );
            $detailsBlock->append($tabBlock);
            $layout->addToParentGroup($name,'detailed_info');
        }

        array_unshift($args, $resultPage);

        return $args;
    }
}
```

This creates blocks for each tab entity and inserts them into the layout. To make them render as tabs we have to make them children of the `product.info.details` block and members of the `detailed_info` group.

We also need to define our custom block type:

```
<?php


namespace Your\Module\Block;


use Your\Module\Api\Data\TabInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Tab extends Template
{
    protected $tab;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        TabInterface $tab,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->tab = $tab;

        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function toHtml() : string
    {
        return $this->tab->getContent();
    }
}
```

This block is assigned a tab and overrides the `toHtml` method to return the tab's content.